# How do I get the scale of DataTable.Column of type Decimal

Tags: .net, sql

I read the database and get a DataSet, the DataTable inside this DataSet specify a column type of "Decimal", is there a way to get the precision and the Scale of that datatype in run time ?

I am using C# .NET

Comment: `.Net System.Decimal` hasn't precision/scale. You must read DB scheme.

Comment: a little more detail will help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server. You can get those information from database by following query.

```
SELECT NUMERIC_PRECISION,NUMERIC_SCALE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
 AND TABLE_NAME = 'YourTable'   
 AND COLUMN_NAME = 'YourColumn'
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this help you ...by using this classes : "server" and "Database" and "Table" and "Column" from this USING below you can access directly to sqlserver's tables and columns

> using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

> ```
>         Server server = new Server("yourServerName");
>         Database db = new Database(server, "yourdatabasename");
>         db.Tables.Refresh();
>         int count = db.Tables.Count;
>         Table tb = (db.Tables["yourTableName"]);
>         if (tb != null)
>         {
>             tb.Columns.Refresh();
>             foreach (Column col in tb.Columns)
>             {
>                 //now you can get anything of your columns directly from sqlserver
>             }
>         }
> ```

Comment: I dont see how that helps me get the precision / scale for the datatype